# How to remove page link in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, bootstrap-4

every time if I add a new page, the link will come out along with a new navigation on my page, I have deleted it in the menu structure but it didn't work

here the image :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0LQq.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not from the sidebar, I add under my navigation code.

```
 <?php
  if (  has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
         wp_nav_menu(array(
        'menu' => 'Main Navigation',
        'container_id' => 'cssmenu',
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'walker' => new Consulting_Menu_Walker()
        )); }
```

thx for help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your page.php file and remove the code, which includes your sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Please check **Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu** checkbox in your menu page if checked then uncheck it. See the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVVcD.png

Comment: yes, I tried it but it didn't work, enable and disable Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu and display box the link it still appear.

Answer (score 0):

It came from sidebar. Either go to widget and remove sidebar widget. or goto page.php & remove sidebar fetching code.